# Only adding some cells in one column

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-science

it's my first post and just started out with programming, but I am looking forward to the journey!

**My Problem:**
For a project, I read out an Excel file with Pandas. Now I want to add only some cells together in the same column.
Concrete: 
I have the population from Age 0-99 and only want to add People above 65+.

Excel Sheet is like:

```
Age | Men | Females
```

Thank you very much for suggestions!

Comment: `df[df'Age']>65]` gives you the part of the data with age 65+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following slicing method:

`df[df['Age']>65]`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to get the rows in which the value of age variable is > 65. Then use this code

```
data['Age']=(data['Age'].loc[data['Age']>65])
```

the values which are below 65 are filled with NaN or remain empty
You can check the min value in this column by writing

```
data.describe(include='all')
```

The min value of age will be 65
Now, if you want to remove the rows which have missing values (in which the age is less than 65)
write,

```
data.dropna(axis=0,how='any')
```

it will remove all the rows with missing values.
Now you have the data in which the age variable of all the rows is greater than 65.
Thank you!!